# Gathering custom number fields in Groovy, and calculating return result (JIRA script runner)

Tags: if-statement, groovy, jira

Getting accustomed to Groovy, I need to gather 2 number custom field values in JIRA, and perform a calculation on those 2 field values, then return that result to another (3rd) custom field using this script. But I am still understanding how global and local variables work. How can I return the calculation based below to a 'finalResult' field as indicated below, my variables valuePA and valueCA are not recognized in the if/then statement. I appreciate any feedback!!

```
FormField paidAmount = getFieldByName("Paid Amount")
def valuePA = paidAmount.getValue()

FormField correctAmount = getFieldByName("Correct Amount")
def valueCA = correctAmount.getValue()


//performing logic on values from correctAmount and paidAmount
def finalResult() {
    if (valuePA <= valueCA) {
return (valuePA / valueCA) * 100
    } else (valueCA < valuePA) {
return ((valueCA - valuePA) / valueCA) * 100
    }
}
```

Then I will take the finalResult and use it to update the 3rd custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass those values to the function

```
def finalResult(a, b) {
    if (a <= b) {
        (a / b) * 100
    } else {
        ((b - a) / a) * 100
    }
}
```

Then

```
def result = finalResult(valuePA, valueCA)
```

Comment: thank you so much, just needed an outside nudge on the logic.

Comment: No worries, have fun!